# It says illegal target for variable annotation.I am not quite getting where the problem is? P.S: try to use only if elif else statements

Tags: python

Write a Python program to input three sides of a triangle. If a Triangle can
be formed with given input, Check whether it forms a `‘right Triangle’` or
`‘Equilateral Triangle’` or `‘Normal Triangle’`. If Triangle cannot be formed,
display `‘Triangle cannot be formed’`.

```py
a=int(input(""))
b=int(input(""))
c=int(input(""))
d=pow((a*a+b*b),0.5)
e=pow((a*a+c*c),0.5)
f=pow((b*b+c*c),0.5)
if a>(b+c) or b>(a+c) or c>(a+b):
    print("Triangle cannot be formed")
else:
    elif a==f or b==e or c==d:
      print("Right Triangle")
    elif a==b and b==c:
      print("Equilateral Triangle")
    else:
      print("Normal Triangle")
```

Comment: Did you mean to not have the `else:`?

Comment: remove first else and fix the indentations and you are good

Comment: I just noticed that there is angles given and not sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue in your code is this line

```
elif a==f or b==e or c==d:
```

You can't have "elif" without initial "if". The structure should look like:

```
a=int(input(""))
b=int(input(""))
c=int(input(""))
d=pow((a*a+b*b),0.5)
e=pow((a*a+c*c),0.5)
f=pow((b*b+c*c),0.5)
if a>(b+c) or b>(a+c) or c>(a+b):
    print("Triangle cannot be formed")
else:
    if a==f or b==e or c==d:
      print("Right Triangle")
    elif a==b and b==c:
      print("Equilateral Triangle")
    else:
      print("Normal Triangle")
```

This code works